# Treating NAs as 0 in denominator of fraction but not numerator

Tags: r

I have three variables:

```
  data.frame(x=c(1, NA, 3), y=3:5, z=c(NA, NA, 3))
```

and I want to create a value that represents the proportion of the total of the three that x is such that

```
x/(x+y+z)
```

would return a vector

```
1/(1+3+0), NA, 3/(3+5+3).
```

How is this possible? I have tried x[is.na(x)] <- 0 then running that code, but that returns 0 for the second value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this should give the expected result

```
 d1[,1]/rowSums(d1, na.rm=TRUE)
 #[1] 0.2500000        NA 0.2727273
```

Or use `recode` from `car` to change NA to 0

```
 library(car)
 d1[,1]/Reduce(`+`, lapply(d1, recode, 'NA=0'))
 #[1] 0.2500000        NA 0.2727273
```

Or

```
 library(qdap)
 d1[,1]/Reduce(`+`,NAer(d1))
 #[1] 0.2500000        NA 0.2727273
```

#### data

```
 d1 <- data.frame(x=c(1, NA, 3), y=3:5, z=c(NA, NA, 3))
```